# Replace pie chart color with gradient

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I have this pie chart

```
pie(c(1,2,1),col=c("black","white","gray"))
```

[image]

I would like to keep the white and black colors as they are, but want to change the gray color with black-to-white gradient where the area next to the black sector starts out in black, then gradually becomes gray, and then further gradually turns into white before reaching the white sector. So the gray color would be replaced with something like this:

[image]

Any thoughts how I can do that? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subdivide a section into multiple sections and apply a colour, from a scale, to each. It requires drawing a line for the outer circle, which is removed in the pie call.

```
# Number of intervals to subdivide - increase for finer detail
n <- 41 
# Generate colours
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "black"))(n) 

# Plot
# lty=0 removes the section lines, which also removes outer border
pie(c(1,2, rep(1/n, n)), col=c("black","white", cols) , lty=0,
                                    labels=c(1,2, rep("", n/2), 3))

# Add in outer circle back in
# radius=0.8 used as this is the pie default
plotrix::draw.circle( 0,0, 0.8)
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ggplot2` package.

First, rearrange your data:

```
x <- c(1,2,1)
labels <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(x = unlist(mapply(x = x, lab = labels, function(x, lab) rep(lab, times = x))))
```

And then, here is the code for the plots

```
pie <- ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(x)))
pie <- pie + geom_bar(width = 1)
pie <- pie + coord_polar(theta = "y") 
pie <- pie + xlab("") + ylab("")
pie + scale_fill_grey()
```